# How to add new field with constant using $project?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

from [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/):

> The $addFields stage is equivalent to a $project stage that explicitly
>   specifies all existing fields in the input documents and adds the new
>   fields.

But if I write:

```
db.projects.aggregate(
        {
            $project: {             
                count: 1            
            }
        }  
)
```

This code doesn't add count to the result.

In contrast:

```
   db.projects.aggregate(
            {
                $addFields: {               
                    count: 1            
                }
            }  
    )
```

This adds `count` field to result.

How to add new field to result using `$project`? I think it is possible because it is equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [$literal](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/) for this task:

```
db.projects.aggregate(
    {
        $project: {
            count: { $literal : 1 }
        }
    }
)
```